# Swift problems with the value of some objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need a little help to rebuild this function:

```
 init(dictionary:[String : AnyObject], acceptedTypes: [String])
    {
        let json = JSON(dictionary)
        name = json["name"].stringValue
        address = json["vicinity"].stringValue

        let lat = json["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
        let lng = json["geometry"]["location"]["lng"].doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)

        photoReference = json["photos"][0]["photo_reference"].string

        var foundType = "restaurant"
        let possibleTypes = acceptedTypes.count > 0 ? acceptedTypes : ["bakery", "bar", "cafe", "grocery_or_supermarket", "restaurant"]
        for type in json["types"].arrayObject as! [String] {
            if possibleTypes.contains(type) {
                foundType = type
                break
            }
        }
        placeType = foundType
    }
```

In another function that is this:

```
 func fetchNearbyPlaces(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        mapView.clear()

        dataProvider.fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate: coordinate, radius:searchRadius, types: previuosViewTappedButtonsArray as! [String] ) { places in
            for place: GooglePlace in places {

                let marker = PlaceMarker(place: place)

                marker.map = self.mapView
            }
        }
    }
```

The app crash at this line:

```
types: previuosViewTappedButtonsArray as! [String]
```

For the error "Could not cast value of type 'UIButton'  to 'NSString' ." Obviously this error arises because previuosViewTappedButtonsArray has a value of type UIButton and not String (all this because I had to modify a viewController changing the tableView with some buttons to select the user preferences).

I'm a beginner in coding so can someone help me to properly modify this code to make it works? (so I would like that the code work with previuosViewTappedButtonsArray as a UIButton value)

```
 var previuosViewTappedButtonsArray = NSMutableArray()
```

is in the same viewController of  func fetchNearbyPlaces() and is an array that contains the info about buttons that have been pressed in the previous view, i also have this func in another class

```
 func fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, types:[String], completion: (([GooglePlace]) -> Void)) -> ()
  {
    var urlString = "http://localhost:10000/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&radius=\(radius)&rankby=prominence&sensor=true"
    let typesString = types.count > 0 ? types.joinWithSeparator("|") : "food"
    urlString += "&types=\(typesString)"
    urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

    if let task = placesTask, task.taskIdentifier > 0 && task.state == .Running {
      task.cancel()
    }

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    placesTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {data, response, error in
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
      var placesArray = [GooglePlace]()
      if let aData = data {
        let json = JSON(data:aData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil)
        if let results = json["results"].arrayObject as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
          for rawPlace in results {
            let place = GooglePlace(dictionary: rawPlace, acceptedTypes: types)
            placesArray.append(place)
            if let reference = place.photoReference {
              self.fetchPhotoFromReference(reference) { image in
                place.photo = image
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion(placesArray)
      }
    }
    placesTask?.resume()
  }
```

i had to change the tableView with six buttons

```
protocol TypesTableViewControllerDelegate: class {
  func typesController(controller: TypesTableViewController, didSelectTypes types: [String])
}

class TypesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  let possibleTypesDictionary = ["bakery":"Bakery", "bar":"Bar", "cafe":"Cafe", "grocery_or_supermarket":"Supermarket", "restaurant":"Restaurant"]
  var selectedTypes: [String]!
  weak var delegate: TypesTableViewControllerDelegate!
  var sortedKeys: [String] {
    return possibleTypesDictionary.keys.sort()
  }


  @IBAction func donePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.typesController(self, didSelectTypes: selectedTypes)
  }

  // MARK: - Table view data source
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return possibleTypesDictionary.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    let key = sortedKeys[indexPath.row]
    let type = possibleTypesDictionary[key]!
    cell.textLabel?.text = type
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: key)
    cell.accessoryType = (selectedTypes!).contains(key) ? .Checkmark : .None
    return cell
  }

  // MARK: - Table view delegate
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let key = sortedKeys[indexPath.row]
    if (selectedTypes!).contains(key) {
      selectedTypes = selectedTypes.filter({$0 != key})
    } else {
      selectedTypes.append(key)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

this was the code (swift 2 version) of the tableView that i had before adding the buttons

Comment: You should add where and how `previuosViewTappedButtonsArray` is defined.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of `previuosViewTappedButtonsArray` is; but you could store the "tappedButton's" title in that array, which would give you a `[String]`

Comment: @vadian right!  var previuosViewTappedButtonsArray = NSMutableArray() is in the same viewController of  func fetchNearbyPlaces() and contains a list of button that have been pressed in the previous view

Comment: try doing  "var previuosViewTappedButtonsArray = [String]()"

Comment: @vadian i edited the question

Comment: Okay that's the declaration. And how is the array populated? And what is the purpose of that array? By the way: Do not use `NSMutableArray / Dictionary` in Swift at all. Use Swift native (strong) types. And this is not Swift 3. The `swift3` tag is misleading.

Comment: @vadian the array is populated with this  IBAction func artTap1(_ sender: Any) {
    if boxArt2.isHidden == false {
          tappedButtonsArray.add(sender)  }    the purpose of the array is to tell to the nextViewController which button have been tapped (the buttons are 6 and represent the user preferences) , i know is not swift 3 but i have already modified the code

Comment: @seran if you want to add "Any" to the array, that array should be allocated in this way: var previousViewTappedButtonsArray: [Any] = []. But seriously, why do you need to store buttons? How are you going to use an object from that array later? There is no such code in your question. If you just need to know what button was tapped, why don't you use an array of title of each button, or an array of tags?

Comment: @Woof i edited the code adding the tableView that i had before putting the buttons, yes i need to know what button was tapped, it's not a bad idea an array of title, but can you make an example so i understand better

Comment: @Woof ok i did it, thanks!

Comment: @seran ok, cool. Let me know if you need some help